# How to write a macro that will expand another macro in C++?

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

Is there a way to write `expand` macro in the following code that will expand the `MAC1` macro first and then output the code? I want the macro `MAC1` to expand first and then the macro `expand` to work on the expanded `MAC1` macro.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

#define MAC1(x) cout<<"tokenize: "<<#x<<endl; x 

#define expand(a) { \  
    string s; \
    s=#a; \  
    cout<<"expanded form: "<<s<<endl;\
    }


using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    MAC1(int z=10;);

    cout<<"the value of z is: "<<z;

    expand(MAC1(int y=11;)) // The output I'm getting here is :
                                // "expanded form: MAC1(int y=11;)"
    // But I want to define expand so that I get output:
    // "expanded form: "cout<<"tokenize: "<<int y=11<<endl; int y=11;"
    // which is basically expand MAC1 first and then convert it into a string and then output it.
   // How can I do that?    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the ## operator? I think that will let you expand a.

Comment: `#define expand2(a) your original definition` `#define expand(a) expand2(a)` Just need an extra hop. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/o8zqv9YrM)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik `expand2` expands `expand` but without expanding `MAC1`.  Maybe I'm not writing right. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I gave you a link to a working demo, which produces the output you claimed you wanted.  What reason do you have to doubt the technique? I'm not sure I quite grasp the nature of the difficulty.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Sorry didn't see the demo. Looks like it works. I will try to understand it now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Isn't `expand(a)` just the same as `expand2(a)`. Can you please explain how is this working?

Comment: It's the way macro expansion works. `expand(MAC1(int y=11;))` doesn't expand to `expand2(MAC1(int y=11;))` as you appear to assume - it expands to `expand2(cout<<"tokenize: "<<"int y=11;<<endl; int y=11;)` . And then *that* is further expanded.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes you're right! When I see Visual Studio it exactly expands like you said.

Comment: I wrote `expand2(MAC1(int d=15;))` but that just stringized the `MAC1(int d=15;)` part. So I am a little confused! Shouldn't it also expand like `expand2(cout<<"tokenize: "<<"int y=11;<<endl; int y=11;)` like you said? Or is there a guide or reference you can suggest where I can understand macros better? @IgorTandetnik

Comment: No, it should not. This is the same as your original code in the question; why do you think this time it'd work differently?

Comment: Is there a detailed guide on multiple macro expansions you can suggest me so I can look it up?